# Do Pakistan, Nigeria, Bangladesh, or Indonesia consider overpopulation to be a problem?

Tags: pakistan, demographics, indonesia, bangladesh, nigeria

Abdel Fattah Al-Sissi said that overpopulation was, along with terrorism, the two real threats to Egypt, and took countermeasures in 2017.

https://www.egypttoday.com/Article/1/40295/What%E2%80%99s-being-done-about-overpopulation-in-Egypt

Do you know if similarly in Pakistan, Nigeria, Bangladesh, and Indonesia, the government and the society consider overpopulation to be a problem (and "how many" is it considered to be a problem), and if yes, which countermeasures have been taken?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it's worth noting that overpopulation is a particular problem for Egypt because about 95% of its land area is inhospitable desert, and the 5% that isn't has been occupied for many thousands of years. I'd expect that even Bangladesh, as overcrowded as it is, has room for more housing; Egypt most likely does not.

Comment: @user2501323 I was not asking if it is a problem (it would be clearly an opinion-based question, because we aren't agree), I'm asking if it is considered as a problem in these countries. India had a lower rate birth than in Pakistan, but yes I'm also interested about demographics in India, if you have information about it.

Comment: This question needs research as there are tons of information available. Specifying a single country (or at least explaining the rationale behind this seemingly random list of countries) might also help make it more manageable.

Comment: I can cut the question in four if people think it is a good idea.

Comment: I'm voting to close unless you can explain what unites these countries.

Comment: I don't know if it was the most clever thing to ask on multiple countries, but yes, it is important.  It is hard to look at estimates giving 700M Nigerians by 2100 and think that this would be in any way shape or form a clever idea, including for them.  Or not be resentful that the world will be asked to help palliate the mess (just like selfish USA CO2 emissions are a problem for everyone).  Knowing that their government is at least trying to fix the problem is good to know. What unites them?:  high density/high population/poor countries (though others could be added).  Vote to reopen.

Comment: [For World Population Day, a look at the countries with the biggest projected gains – and losses – by 2100](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2019/07/10/for-world-population-day-a-look-at-the-countries-with-the-biggest-projected-gains-and-losses-by-2100/),  That 3 out of 4 included, with the exception of Bangladesh which will likely lose massive farmlands to global warming sea level rises.  Pakistan is at 240/km2 right now, will go up to 4-450, but in a country without a lot of flat land.

Comment: @fedor - I do not quite agree with the question closure, but I am very curious why these four countries in particular?

Comment: There is not one big reason. I know that Nigeria, Indonesia and Pakistan are and will still be in the future ones of the most populated countries (I didn't ask for India, because their birth rate doesn't seem so high). Bangladesh is a different case, but I know it's the most dense country (if we forgot small countries like Singapore). I don't understand why close the question now (T-Pioniere (thanks to him or her) already answers fully and clearly). Maybe I will ask similar questions for other countries (but, in the future I will limit by one country per question for more clarity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until now, the governments of **Nigeria**, **Bangladesh**, **Indonesia** think population problems already appeared in their country. **Pakistan** should do more to solve it.

***Actives:***

**Nigeria:** *free contraception, taking steps to discourage people who are looking to have large families.*

**Pakistan:** *some people want a new law for controlling the population.*

**Bangladesh:** *given much stress on the population control by identifying it as one of the main problems of the country. Some people will help the government.*

**Indonesia:** *family planning education and program, looking forward for meeting its 2025 target of reducing fertility rates to 2.1 children per woman.*

**Nigeria: *Yes.***

> The Nigerian government has been doing its best to help curb a rapid growth in population. They have offered free contraception over the past 10 years or so and they have even started taking steps to discourage people who are looking to have large families. The government is banking on smaller families as a way to secure financial salvation in the future. They are looking toward territories like Thailand – another area with large population growth issues – as a model for their current strategy.
>
> [Nigeria Population, World Population Review](https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/nigeria-population)

**Pakistan: *Almost no now, yes in 1950s.***

> ... the current population of Pakistan is nearly 210 million.  It is expected that the population of Pakistan can cross 300 million by 2050 which is an alarming situation for Pakistan. ... Family planning is an issue where Pakistan is not concerned. It is the responsibility of the government to implement new laws for controlling the population and there should be some strict rules for family planning. Population is the root of every destruction in the country.
>
> [*"Population problems"*,*"Pakistan Today"*, Sameen Abid, Turbat](https://www.pakistantoday.com.pk/2020/01/29/population-problems/)

> ... In the late 1950s the Pakistan government initiated a family planning program. The program has trained medical and paramedical personnel in family planning, added family planning services to existing medical centers, planned for a National Research Institute of Family Planning, employed mobile units to reach outlying areas, conducted limited clinical studies on some contraceptives, and used mass media advertising. Only India and Japan are doing more with government-sponsored family planning. A weak organizational structure and an inadequate number of trained personnel are the main weakness of the program. It is too early to assess the success of the program. A 10-point reduction in annual birth rates will be considered successful.
>
> [*"Population and population policy in Pakistan"*, *"Marriage Fam Living"* 1963 Feb;25(1):62-8. W P Mauldin](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12275622/)

**Bangladesh: *yes.***

> However, the government of Bangladesh has given much stress on the population control by identifying it as one of the main problems of the country. So, we should help the government in this respect.
>
> [*"Population problem in Bangladesh Paragraph, Composition and Essay"*, Ontaheen](https://www.ontaheen.com/population-problem-in-bangladesh/#:%7E:text=Population%20Problem%20in%20Bangladesh.%20Population%20explosion%20means%20rapid,of%20Bangladesh%20is%20less%20than%20her%20vast%20population.)

**Indonesia: *yes, but not very successful.***

> Unfortunately, Indonesia's attempts at family planning education and population control have not been very successful, and it's hard to say how sustainable the country's growth will be.
>
> [Indonesia Population 2020 (Live), World Population Review](https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/indonesia-population)

> JAKARTA (Reuters) - Family planning efforts have stagnated in Indonesia over a decade of democratic rule and the world’s fourth most populous country risks squandering a so-called demographic dividend that a youthful, productive population should deliver. ... "The family planning program needs revitalization ... and we can safely say that if the total fertility rate isn't reduced soon, Indonesia's demographic bonus will not be achieved." Indonesia failed to meet its 2014 target of reducing fertility rates to 2.1 children per woman, the family planning agency has said. Health officials now hope the target can be reached by 2025.
>
> ["Indonesia to face opportunity, risk as population grows by a third", Reuters, Kanupriya Kapoor](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-indonesia-population-idUSBREA0T0GK20140130)